# execute su -c over ssh

Tags: ssh, unix, su

I am trying to check the BIOS version of a server over SSH, a command that requires root privileges:

```
ssh remote-server su -c dmidecode
```

but this of course fails with the error:

> standard in must be a tty

How do I make this work?  I cannot use sudo, and when I try to log in as root@remote-server, it won't accept the password I use for the 'su' command.  I am using RedHat Enterprise Linux 4.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into using sudo instead of "su -c"

Comment: as I specified "I cannot use sudo"

Comment: I'd love for there to have been more information as to why "I cannot use sudo" was the case.

Comment: @dannysauer Not all OS's have it. I am here trying to solve the same problem, except that I'm not on RedHat like OP. I'm on a unix variant with no sudo. I'm curious as to why OP cannot use it on RedHat, but I'm grateful anyway that the question has been asked.

Comment: sudo builds on all of the UNIX variants I'm familiar with, but I'll agree that it's not installed (or configured) on all of them.  I was really more curious why it wasn't configured there (I think - it's been a few years). :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `-t` to force ssh to allocate a tty:

```
ssh -t -t remote-user su -c dmidecode
```

You might also consider allowing root to ssh directly. If you're using public key authentication, this may be more secure as you won't be passing a password around. If you decide to do this, consider blocking root logins from anywhere except your trusted IP addresses by putting the following in `/etc/security/access.conf`:

```
+ : root : 10.20.30.40
- : root : ALL EXCEPT LOCAL
```

and make sure `UsePAM` isn't disabled in `sshd_config`

Comment: Any reason you included two `-t`s in your example?

Comment: According to the man page, multiple -t options "force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty"

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Fedora. It allows the script to prompt me for my password, but my password displays as plaintext, and when I press enter, it just hangs.

Comment: @Chris that's a different problem. Try asking a new question.

Comment: @Heath thanks for the comment about the double -t, that works for me on Centos

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just log in to the remote server as a standard user and then use *sudo*?

You could also try quoting the command to be executed by ssh, as in

```
ssh remote-server 'su -c dmidecode'
```

or

```
ssh remote-server "su -c dmidecode"
```

Comment: -1 because quoting the command isn't going to resolve his lack of a terminal. +1 for suggesting sudo. It's a wash.

Comment: as I specified "I cannot use sudo"